# Remapping find-file to helm-find-files

Tags: helm, keymap, find-file

I have Helm installed and added this line to the end of the init file:

```
(define-key global-map [remap find-file] 'helm-find-files)
```

So, when I restart Emacs and try `C-x C-f` it executes `helm-find-files`. But all subsequent `C-x C-f` are executing plain `find-file`. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by subsequent? Once `helm-find-files` is active, `helm-map` takes  over control, I guess.

Comment: @Timm I'm executing `C-x C-f` first-time in a new Emacs session, it goes `helm-find-files`. Ok. Next time I'm trying to find a file in this session by `C-x C-f` it goes `find-file` - no Helm.

Comment: I doubt this question is answerable without seeing more of your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there might be something interesting going on with your helm-mode activiation/config. At any rate, helm-find-files, as well as helm-M-x, were removed from default-on status in helm-mode by [this commit](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/1de1701c73b15a86e99ab1c5c53bd0e8659d8ede).

I wonder if you can get that functionality back by customizing 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist'. In that structure, one option is to delete:

```
'find-file': nil  
'execute-extended-command': nil
```

Alternatively, you can also set those entries to:

```
'find-file': helm-find-file
'execute-extended-command': helm-M-x
```

There is a third option, but it will be left as an exercise for the reader.

For what it is worth, when I first started using helm, helm-find-files especially caused me some serious confusion for a bit, in that a back arrow dropped a whole word instead of moving characters around. I am not responsible for this change, but I think it makes sense. As for your issue, I think maybe the alist is somehow getting processed by default but not for new instances or something?